unique dependent type for decltype(dependent-expression) in C++
I have a doubt about what is the effect for decltype(dependent-expression) to determine a "unique dependent type".
This other discussion stackoverflow_link deals with this topic but it just focuses on the match between declarations and definitions.
In the following example godbolt_link
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct X{};

template<typename T>
void f(){
    T t;
    X<decltype(t+t)> a;
    X<T> b;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<decltype(a),decltype(b)> << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    f<int>();
}

the output with gcc 14.2 is "true", which means that decltype(t+t) was not considered as a different type compared to T (and I like this).
So, I am considering that when the standard reads about decltype(e) for dependent expressions, it is discussing the type equivalence and requires that two equivalent template-ids refer to the same template instantiation, which means that in fact there is no rule that forbids to consider the same instantiation even when decltype(e) owns a 'formally' unique (dependent) type.
Is this a correct thinking, or there is some other explicit aspect from the standard that leads to "true" in my example ? It should be about the effects for types to be 'dependent', and/or about the interpretation of the term "unique" for the dependent type of decltype(e).

Please reference the paragraph of the standard and specify the version if you want to discuss what it is saying.

In C++20 draft n4849 it is 13.6-(4), but you can also find the reference in the other stack overflow link that I posted. I also guess that's the only point of the standard where the expression "unique dependent type" is present. Thank you.

OK I see. As I read it, it is a unique type for purposes of distinguishing between templates. For example, template <auto x> void foo(decltype(x)) {} and template <auto x> void foo(decltype(x-x)) {} are definitions of two different templates (legal), rather than a redefinition of the same template (illegal), even if x later is instantiated to be an int in both cases. Then of course the two instantiations will be simply ambiguous to call, because they have the same exact name and signature (the parameter type is int and not anything unique). But they are still two different entities.

(Contd) So basically I think you think the same way I think :)

I see you write "for purposes of distinguishing between templates", with focus on template DECLARATIONS, correct ? I mean, in my case it is about template implicit instantiations, instead, and there the compiler does not consider decltype(t+t) as a "unique", different type. And, in addition, still the same doubt: is there some point where the standard states the "purpose" of (unique) dependent types ? Thank you.

In the instantiation, decltype(t+t) is just e.g. int, the same  as any other int. It is not unique anything. If it would be different from int and every other type it would be rather useless. This is my understanding anyway.

sure, even in my opinion I like it is int there. However, my focus is about formal standard rules, and I fill I did not get yet a complete answer to the initial set of questions (but thank for your efforts). Do you believe the compiler developers are free to consider two different implicit specializations in my example ? If, instead, it is a must to determine two equivalent specializations, do you believe there is a formal point from the standard for that (which, for example, limits the purposes of the 'unicity' of the dependent type) ?

The standard is not a mathematical absolute given to us by an infallible deity. The rules are as formal and precise as the committee members cared/managed to make them. That is, not at all at times. If in doubt, ask for a clarification from the committee.

ok, of course the standard may contain ambiguities, lacks, and so on, but it is still not clear to me what is the opinion for this case: an ambiguity ? a lack of precision ? a ''too much" relying on common sense ? anything else ? I hope you may answer in the scope of my two questions from last previous comment: 1) do you believe the compiler developers are free to consider two different implicit specializations in my example ? Otherwise, 2) do you believe there is any formal point from the standard leading to be "a must" the result of two equivalent specializations ? Really thank you.

If compiler developers consider decltype(t+t) a type different from int when t is instantiated as int, their compilers will get flooded by bug reports and disappear from the market, that's all. That's because C++ developers expect this type to be int, and use this expectation in their programs today, standardese be damned. If somebody comes with a formal proof that the standard requires this type to be different from int, this would be considered by many, including me, a defect in the standard.

I think one way to interpret this is to say that only templates have dependent types, template (full) specializations don't, because a specialization doesn't have template parameters. IANA(L)L so I can't guarantee it's correct.

I think "unique dependent type" has a fundamentally different meaning than "unique type" - ie, it is not a unique type that is dependent, and a dependent type is not just a kind of type.  Determining which dependent types are equal is required in order to work out which functions are the same function, for example, prior to instantiating the template with types.  I wasn't able to figure out how to justify this from standards text, however, in the time I spent on it.

Thank you Adam for your contribute about possible lack of explicit statements from the standard.
Sure, I agree it is a 'unique' 'dependent type' (not a 'dependent' 'unique type'), and the focus was exactly on where 'dependent types' matter.
Hope the standard can clarify somewhere in the future the contexts where dependent types are considered, if not yet present.
Just an additional point to be confirmed: do you believe that compilers which consider two different implicit specializations in my example would not satisfy the standard ?
